# Parse Files Migration

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-s3

I have migrated parse server and pointed all the client application to the new standalone parse server. I have used the [parse files utils](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils) to migrate existing files from parse to aws s3. The migration completed properly and I can see the images in my s3 bucket. There is an option to add prefix to the migrated files which I have done.

Now on the client website when I check the URL of the images they are the same starting with 'tfss' which means they are still getting rendered from parse hosted S3 bucket. What are the steps I need to take to make sure the images are getting rendered from my s3 bucket?

Do I need to remove the fileKey from parse server or what?

The config that I used for file migration is as follows

```
module.exports = {
  applicationId: <APPLICATION ID>,
  masterKey: <MASTER KEY>,
  mongoURL: <NEW MONGODB URL>,
  serverURL: "https://api.parse.com/1",
  filesToTransfer: 'all',
  renameInDatabase: false,
  renameFiles: false,
  aws_accessKeyId: <NEW S3 BUCKET ACCESS KEY>,
  aws_secretAccessKey: <NEW S3 BUCKET SECRET>,
  aws_bucket: <BUCKET NAME>,
  aws_bucketPrefix: "prod_migrated_"
};
```

Thanks in advance. Please help with further steps.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your Parse-Server configuration, it is a bit hard to know how you have it setup, but here are a few things to check:

- If you have all your files in S3 and all the clients are pointing to your new Parse Server then you can remove the `fileKey` parameter from your Parse Server configuration. This will prevent Parse Server from formatting the file URL with the hosted hostname and fileKey.
- Verify in your Parse Server `filesAdapter` configuration for S3, you have set a proper `baseUrl`, `bucketPrefix` and `directAccess` parameters as stated in the documentation. The baseUrl should be something similar to `https://<BUCKET_NAME>.s3.amazonaws.com`.
- Verify that you have also setup the proper bucket policy to grant read privileges to be able to get the URL (see S3 adapter documentation). You can verify this by trying to access one of the images in your S3 bucket in the browser.